# Open Neighborhood Existence of a Subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Assume we have the subset X=$(−1, 1) × {0} ⊂ R^2$ and the open ball Y=$B(0, 1) ⊂ R^2$. Prove there is no $ \epsilon > 0$ s.t. for all x in X, a neighborhood of radius  of x is a subset of Y.

So Y contains X and I know that if X is compact and in Y, then there will exist such $ \epsilon > 0$, but X is definitely not compact here so I am not sure how to show the non-existence of such $ \epsilon $.

Answer (score 1):

Prove by contradiction. Suppose such an $\epsilon$ exists. Then consider the point $x=(1-\epsilon/3,0)$. Then $y=(1+\epsilon/3,0)$ is in the $\epsilon$ ball around $x$ but it is not in $Y$.

Comment: why choose /3? thanks

Comment: @jamesblack Because $\epsilon /3 +\epsilon /3  <\epsilon $. If I choose $\epsilon /2$ I would not get  a point in the open ball of radius $\epsilon $